# Does @NodeEntityScan exist in Spring Boot 1.4.0.RELEASE?

Tags: spring-boot, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j-4

According to http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.4.0.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-neo4j there is a @NodeEntityScan annotation that:

> You can customize entity scanning locations using the @NodeEntityScan annotation.

According to http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.4.0.M3/api/org/springframework/boot/neo4j/NodeEntityScan.html it existed in version spring-boot 1.4.0.M3

But http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.4.0.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/boot/neo4j/NodeEntityScan.html suggests it doesn't exist in 1.4.0.RELEASE and I can't find any mention of it.

Does this annotation exist in spring boot 1.4.0.RELEASE ? Is this a case where the documentation has not been updated? What should be used instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring Boot 1.4 has the generic annotation `org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.domain.EntityScan` ([JavaDoc](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/domain/EntityScan.html)), which registers the packages to scan for entities for JPA, Neo4J, MongoDB, Cassandra and Couchbase.